# Access the php value on the same page using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web

i am trying to echo the value entered by the user in the input tag using jquery and ajax .
the following is my code

```js
< script src = "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" > < /script>     <
  script type = "text/JavaScript" >
  function showMessage() {
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'value_pass.php',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
        var_PHP_data: message
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert("success");
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //case error
      }
    });

  } <
  /script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  Enter message: <input type="text" id="message">
  <input type="submit" onclick="showMessage()" value="submit" />
  <?php echo "hi".$_GET['var_PHP_data'];?>
</body>

</html>
```

My php script is:

```
<?php 
echo "hi".$_GET['var_PHP_data'];
?>
```

the code alert the success prompt , but i am not able to access the value using GET , any pointers on what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post your php script too

Comment: `<?php echo "hi".$_GET['var_PHP_data'];?>`

Comment: Are you trying to get value using form submit or ajax?

Comment: i am trying to get the value inside a variable using ajax

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this on same page add your php script at the top of the page that handle your ajax request

Like this

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['var_PHP_data'])){
  echo "hi".$_GET['var_PHP_data'];
  die;
}?>

<!-- rest of your html code start from here -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  Enter message: <input type="text" id="message">
  <input type="submit" onclick="showMessage()" value="submit" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using ajax, follow below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  Enter message: <input type="text" id="message">
  <input type="submit" onclick="showMessage()" value="submit" />
 <span id = 'PHP_data'></span>
</body>

</html>


<script src = "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" > < /script>
  <script type = "text/JavaScript" >
  function showMessage() {
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'value_pass.php',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
        var_PHP_data: message
      },
      success: function(data) {
      message1 = "Hi "+message
       $('#PHP_data').html(message1);
        alert("success");
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //case error
      }
    });

  } 
  </script>
```

If you are using form submit use below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method ='GET'>
  Enter message: <input type="text" id="message" name = "message">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
 <?php if(isset($_GET['message'])){
 echo "hi".$_GET['message'];
  die;
} ?>
 </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the above code works just fine , but instead of getting the value inside the span tag , how can i get it inside a variable.. i tried `$_GET` but that didnt work out